# populous and politically important

Tags: articles

The definite article **the** is used before a proper noun when it is qualified by an adjective.

example

> The immortal Shakespeare.
>
> The great Caesar.

But in the following sentence

[**Populous and politically important** Uttar Pradesh brings up the rear on the overall Health Index with a low score of 28.61, while the national leader, Kerala, has scored 74.01.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/scoring-on-health/article28159373.ece)

I think **the** should be used before **populous and politically important** because *populous* and *politically important* are adjective and **Uttar pradesh** is a proper noun.

Comment: The usage of articles is very complicated, and I can't find a complete and errorless guide on the internet so far. For example, _Collins Cobuild English Guides 3: Articles_ has 120 pages. See [this comment here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503188/usage-of-articals-e-g-when-do-we-use-a-singular-noun-on-its-own-without-an-art#comment1215658_503194), and also that question. Maybe he'll answer this question @Shoe.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your examples. In reality, I think mean to say that you put an article before an *adjective* that comes before a proper noun. And you are correct. There *should* be an article there.

Answer (score -1):

I found the explanation in *COLLINS COBUILD ENGLISH GUIDES 3: ARTICLES by Roger Berry*

The short answer is - No, you shouldn't place an article before **Uttar pradesh**, because it's an administrative region of a country.

In ***7.3 Geographical and place names without an article***, p57:

> Political and administrative regions of countries, for example:
>
> **California**, **Hampshire**.
>
> ...in a little valley of **Bavaria**.
>
> ...at his home in **Kent**.

In your question, *Uttar Pradesh* is a state in northern India, so it is not preceded by an article.

However, the 2 examples in your question have "the" before names(proper nouns). This is just stressing, as explained below:

In ***7.13 Personal names***, p63:

> You can stress the definite article with names of people to mean
>   someone famous: 'I met Paul McCartney the other day.' 'You mean
>   **the** Paul McCartney?'

A more general usage is also described in ***4.14 Stressed 'the' meaning 'best'***, p34:

> People sometimes stress the definite article to indicate that
>   something is the best, most fashionable, or only thing of a particular
>   kind. For example, someone might say 'It's **the** place to go' (with
>   the pronounced /ði:/) when referring to a discotheque or club which is
>   very good or fashionable.
>
> Billiards is **the** game.
>
> The foregoing scenario in no way pretends to present **the** answer to
>   urban transportation problems.

In that book, I didn't find examples that has an adjective right before the proper noun. But I think it probably doesn't matter. Otherwise the book should have noted.